# Excel - display text different to the actual value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to have a a cell that has the value 1,2,3 ... or 10 but it will show some text - but when I use the cell value in formulas it should use the numbers!

For example:

- Cell A1 displays a word `Apple` but has a value of 1.
- Cell B1 displays a word `Orange` but has a value of 2.
- Cell C1 will have a formula `=A1+B1`, but would display a value of 3.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to add a $ value to items but diisplay their Name instead of actual $ value.  Later I can make lists such as "Customer basket contains Aplle, Orange" total value = $3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with custom format:

Select cell A1, go to Format Cells->Number->Category->Customer and enter `"Apple"`in the Type field.

Repeat the process for all other cells.

However, note that this "information hiding" is not best practice, as this makes your file hard to audit/debug later. Better use a hidden column to store the values - and type the names directly!

Comment: @ Peter Albert - how exactly do I use a hidden column to store the values - and type the names directly?

Comment: Store the numbers 1 to 10 in A1 to A10. Select column A, right click the column header and select "Hide". Type "Apple", ... in B1 to B10. Use A1 to A10 in any formula you need to refer to the "underlying" value.

Answer (score 5):

This is a valuable thing to be able to do, because it can make your spreadsheet more readable.

1. Define Apple and Orange to be names whose values are 1 and 2. To do this, the best way is to put the words Apple and Orange in cells `A1` and `A2`.
2. Then in cells `B1` and `B2`, put the values 1 and 2.
3. Now use `Insert->Name->Create` to tell Excel you want these four cells to be a dictionary. (They don't use that word.)
4. Now you can use "Apple" and "Orange" anywhere in a formula and they will be replaced during calculation with the numbers 1 and 2.
5. Type the words Apple and Orange into, say, cells `D1` and `D2`. Then in, say, cell `F1`, enter the formula: `=INDIRECT(D1)+INDIRECT(D2)`. The result displayed in `F1` will be 3.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft Excel 2016, You can do the below.

- A1 to A3 => Enter names Apple, Orange, etc. to the cells
- B1 to B3 => Enter their respective values you want (1, 2, ...)
- Right Click on A1 and select the below option 'Define Name...'
- Now, for 'refers to', give the respective B column cell and do this for the rest of the
  A column cells.
- Hide the B column