# Is there an excel function which displays a string but outputs a value when referenced?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Let's say if the function called **"LABEL"**.

Then in cell **A1** I would enter `=LABEL(4,"Four Apples")` and it would render as:

Four Apples

But if I performed a calculation, say `=A1+2` I would get **6**, not #VALUE!

There are a number of applications where I would find this very useful, I know something similar can be achieved using custom number formats but this wouldn't solve my problem in all the instances.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can construct a function like this, but it would require a *VBA* macro.  Is a macro solution acceptable?

Comment: I was hoping there was something in vanilla excel that I'd missed, but if that's the only option and you don't mind helping me to create a custom function, then I would appreciate it :)  But I know it is a bit cheeky to just ask for code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel - display text different to the actual value?](http://superuser.com/questions/569642/excel-display-text-different-to-the-actual-value)

Comment: It looks like that question is in fact the same as mind (couldn't find it when I searched)  However I did ask for a solution other than custom formats.  Was hoping for a formula but yeah it does look like my choices are either formatting or VBA

Answer (score 2):

You can **force the format.**  For example, if you place any number in the cell and format the cell to:

```
"Four Apples";"Four Apples";"Four Apples";
```

The cell will **display** Four Apples but still retain the numeric value (*as viewed in the Formula Bar*)

[image]

Comment: This is probably my best option, I did mention this in the original post but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Gary's Student already asked if you want to use VBa (which is how I'd rather do it) in a comment of your post which you didn't yet answer, however, you could possibly use this solution if you only want to use Worksheet Formula (I use the word `solution` loosely, hacking to heck is better)!

Now, this answer is based upon the information you've given. The only example you gave is "Four Apples"

Assume you have the following in Sheet1

```
    A                B                    
1  four apples     
2  six oranges     
3                    =sum(5 + A1)
4                    =sum(A2 / 2)
```

Where B3 and B4 are to show results, not the actual formula

The only way is with this hack. In worksheet 2, create a look up such as

```
       A                 B
1     one                1
2     two                2 
3     three              3
```

etc

Then,  you can use the following

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),Sheet2!A1:B6,2,FALSE)+10) 'Look up the four apples and add 5

=SUM(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),Sheet2!A1:B6,2,FALSE)/2) 'Look up the six oranges and divide by 2
```

Comment: Yeah I've come up with a few workarounds, unfortunately they all require an extra column with substitutions.  Looks like it's either a macro or just time for me to design better spreadsheets that don't require this.